# Safari image height in CSS grid

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, safari

I have issues in mobile safari, where an image is exceeding the grid height. Chrome is working fine...
Here how it looks like in Chrome:

[image]

And how it looks like on my iPhone:

[image]

Following is my code (simplified):

```
          <div
        style={{
          gridTemplateColumns: '25% 55% 20%',
          display: 'grid',
          minHeight: '20vh'
        }}
      >
          <img
            src={this.props.parent.sliderPhotos[0]}
            style={{
              objectFit: 'cover',
              width: '100%',
              height: '100%'
            }}
          />

        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'yellow',
          }}
        ></div>
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'red',
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>
```

Styling with height 100% and max-height did not work. Also flex-direction: "column" and padding-top: "100%" are not working.

Any more ideas on how it will work in both browsers?

Answer (score 1):

- It's bug on mobile safari. Described here: [tweet](https://twitter.com/sitnikcode/status/1288097180721377280)
- Check this out: [github repo](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-100vh-fix)